# How to stop s3 from listing some of the content?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

It is an example.

[image]

What setting of S3 causes the s3 server to a listing of bucket content?

**EDIT:**

I have followed [Céline Aussourd's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/695859/12364) and turned off the list of the s3 bucket. But unfortunately the cloudfront has cached the result and is still serving it.

Here is the bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Public webserver policy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "readonly policy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::test2/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try to invalidate the objects in Cloudfront? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Comment: You're right. I need to invalidate the path  '/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listing of the bucket content is possible when Everyone has the permission to List.

In your bucket Properties > Permissions

Grantee: Everyone to List (see picture below)
[image]

Comment: The listing is still available from the url (which is a frontfront server). I have updated my question to reflect this.